# MoPub's ViewBinder fails placing TextView in native ad

Tags: android, mopub

I'm trying to place a native ad using this tutorial https://github.com/mopub/mopub-android-sdk/wiki/Native-Ads-Integration

And even though I set the view binder correctly (and I see its values right) the logcat prints out "Attempted to add text (My Dummy Ad) to null TextView."

This is the beginning of my getView in my BaseAdapter:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (moPubNativeResponse != null && mAdapterHelper.isAdPosition(position)) {
        View adView = mAdapterHelper.getAdView(convertView, parent, moPubNativeResponse, viewBinder, null);
        return adView;
    }
```

Know why?

Answer (score 0):

Old question (and probably older MoPub version), but I ran into this message in LogCat today and found NativeViewHolder is calling addTextView() for all components of a native ad- even those not specified in the request parameters. I resolved it by simply commenting the log message; you could also add simple null checks for the TextViews in the update() function instead of letting it fall through to AddTextView().

```
private void addTextView(@Nullable final TextView textView, @Nullable final String contents) {
    if (textView == null) {
        // MoPubLog.d("Attempted to add text (" + contents + ") to null TextView.");
        return;
    }
    ...
}
```

or

```
void update(@NonNull final NativeResponse nativeResponse) {
    if (titleView != null) addTextView(titleView, nativeResponse.getTitle());
    if (textView != null) addTextView(textView, nativeResponse.getText());
    if (callToActionView != null) addTextView(callToActionView, nativeResponse.getCallToAction());
    nativeResponse.loadMainImage(mainImageView);
    nativeResponse.loadIconImage(iconImageView);
}
```

Note: This solution is only possible if you're importing the MoPub SDK as a library module (and can therefore edit its source).